# 条件つきvalidationをymlで定義する方法

Tags: symfony2

symfony2のフォームvalidation機能をymlで定義する際、Aというフィールドのvalueが1の場合のみBというフィールドをrequiredにしたいのですが、そのような条件付きvalidationのymlでの書き方を教えてください。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

requiredにしたいという動機がどこにあるのかで対応方法が変わると思います。
フォーム上(ブラウザ側)で制御したい場合は、Symfonyで行うよりJavaScript側で対応したほうがいいと思います。

もし「Aというフィールドが「Aというフィールドのvalueが1の場合のみ、Bというフィールドが空だったらバリデーションエラーにする」という条件なら、Callbackを使うことで対応できます。

Yaml側

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
AppBundle\Entity\Author:
    constraints:
        - Callback: [validate]
```

Entity側

```
<?php
  use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;


  class Author 
  {
    private $a;

    private $b;

    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
      if (!empty($this->a) && empty($this->b)) {
        $context->buildViolation('Aを入力している場合はBを必ず入力してください。')
          ->atPath('b')
          ->addValidation();          
      }        
    }


  }
```

このようにコールバックバリデーションを利用すれば、柔軟にバリデーションする事が可能になります。

詳しくはSymfonyのドキュメントを参照してください。情報が細かく記載されています。
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html